# How to extend inner nested objects into multiple objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

In Node.js, I want to convert to extend the nested objects into an array, details as follwing:

```
 {
"topic":"myTopic",
"content":{
    "name": {
        "tom1" : {
            "value": "String",
        },
        "tom2" : {
            "value": "String",
        },
        "tom3" : {
            "value": "String",
        }
    }
}
}
```

convert and extend to following format

```
[{
"topic":"myTopic",
"content":{
    "name": {
        "tom1" : {
            "value": "String",
        }
    }
}
},

{
"topic":"myTopic",
"content":{
    "name": {           
        "tom2" : {
            "value": "String",
        }
    }
 }
 },
{
"topic":"myTopic",
"content":{
    "name": {           
        "tom3" : {
            "value": "String",
        }
    }
}
}]
```

Comment: Okay. What's your question?

Comment: I have multiple names inner the objects, is there a good way to extend and generate a new array, inside this new array, each one has one name

Comment: Why are `topic` and `content` properties still in the same object? By which rule you determine objects should be split or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like :

```
var result = []; // contains the array you're looking for
var test = { "topic":"myTopic", "content":{ "name": { "tom1" : { "value": "String", }, "tom2" : { "value": "String", }, "tom3" : { "value": "String", } } } };
Object.keys(test.content.name).map((e,i) => { 
    let temp = {}; 
    temp[e] = test.content.name[e]; 
    result.push({topic: test.topic, content: { name: temp }}); 
});
```

Does this help you ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
x = { "topic":"myTopic", "content":{ "name": { "tom1" : { "value": "String", }, "tom2" : { "value": "String", }, "tom3" : { "value": "String", } } } };

console.log(Object.keys(x.content.name).map((n) => { 
let y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)); 
y.content.name = {}; 
y.content.name[n] = x.content.name[n]; 
return y; 
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` and some of the `Object` methods:

```js
function splitObject(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj.content.name).map( key => Object.assign({}, {
        content: { name: { [key]: obj.content.name[key] } }
    }) );
}

const obj = { 
    topic: "myTopic", 
    content: { 
        name: { 
            tom1: { 
                value: "String", 
            }, 
            tom2: { 
                value: "String", 
            }, 
            tom3: { 
                value: "String", 
            } 
        } 
    } 
};

const result = splitObject(obj);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```